# jQuery optimise code patterns

Tags: javascript, jquery

Afternoon all,

I have 2 blocks of jQuery code with a lot of repeating ... I was wondering if there was any way of simplifying it in terms of lines and/or performance.

The 2 blocks are as follow:

```
$("#intro").css('min-height',$(window).height()-88);
$("#trabalhos").css('min-height',$(window).height()-88);
$("#fotografia").css('min-height',$(window).height()-88);
$("#cv").css('min-height',$(window).height()-88);
$("#contactos").css('min-height',$(window).height()-88);
```

And:

```
$('.portfolio').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#portfolio').offset().top-88},'slow'); });
$('.cv').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#cv').offset().top-88},'slow'); });
$('.trabalhos').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#trabalhos').offset().top-88},'slow'); });
$('.fotografia').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#fotografia').offset().top-88},'slow'); });
$('.contactos').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#contactos').offset().top-88},'slow'); });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine your code using multiple selectors

```
$("#intro,#trabalhos,#fotografia,#cv,#contactos").css('min-height', $(window).height() - 88);

$('.portfolio,.cv,.trabalhos,.fotografia,.contractos').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#'+$(this).attr('class')).offset().top - 88; // <-- this assuming you only have one class
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: Wasn't working ... but I removed the last ; and now is perfect! :) Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can combine selectors into a single statement, separating them with comma.

```
$('#intro, #trabalhos, #fotografia, #cv, #contactos').css('min-height',$(window).height()-88);
```

Comment: So much more simple! I forgot I could do this! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

for which id's your using same css give them a common class 
  and then

```
     $(".common_class").css('min-height',$(window).height()-88);


  is it OK.
```

Comment: LOL! Sometimes we're really that much dumb! Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @moha-gade: I accepted Wirey's answer cause his answer fixex both problems I had